Get nullable results from System.Data.SQLite for a string for multiple columns (without if check)
Tried to find by myself, no luck.
I have classes with a lot of properties internal string? Driver { get; set; } as example.
Im converting SQLDataReader object to the class: swTmpObject.Driver = item.GetString(item.GetOrdinal("driver")).
The property is nullable.
But as I understand GetString cannot take Null to it.
I can use IsDBNull to check every field before converting. But I have a lot of properties.
Also I have an option to use string a = item.GetValue(item.GetOrdinal("driver")).ToString(), but I prefer using Null instead.
Can I make it some how more efficient?
Thanks

Yes, you need to check on a per-column basis. Or: let a tool like Dapper do all the mapping for you! Then it doesn't matter how many columns you have, and you can't fat-finger a column.
